# Solicitation Frequency

Tags: mailing

More and more donors over the last few months have been asking to have custom Solicitation Frequency - IE: Once a year, once every six months.  I can't seem to find a spot within CIVICRM to indicate this within their record.  Is there a spot I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, but you could create one with a custom field - **Administer menu >> Customize Data and Screens >> Custom Fields**.